# Android 2.2 SDK - Create Spinner from Map?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-2.2-froyo

Basically, I want to associate a "selected" option with an id, so instead of doing this (my current way):

```
            Vector spinnerList = new Vector();
            spinnerList.addElement("No");
            spinnerList.addElement("Yes");
```

I'd be doing something like this (the Hashtable/Vector is just for Blackberry compatability):

```
            String id = "3";
            Hashtable spinnerMap = new Hashtable();
            spinnerMap.put(id, "No");
            spinnerMap.put(id, "Yes");
```

Currently, a selected "option" from the spinner prints out 0 or 1 (based on the "No", "Yes"). So, my question is, if I'm setting the spinners programatically from a map whose values I don't know (I just know ids), how do I do this?

```
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerList);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    System.out.println("Selected: " + arg2);

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    System.out.println("Nothing selected: " + arg0);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. What exactly do you want to accomplish?
If you just want to display different data than a simple list of strings I think you should consider creating a custom adapter.

Comment: Let's say I'm inflating multiple spinners, meaning I have multiple "Yes" or "No" drop-downs, each aassociated with an id...let's say 3, 4, 5, etc.  When I select "No" from one of the spinners, I would get the id of selection 0,1 ("Yes" or "No"), but also the id of the spinner (3, 4, 5).

Comment: something like this?
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                    System.out.println("Selected: " + arg2);
String selectedSpinner=getString(v.getId());
                }
But I still see no real question from you, so it's hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your map, and you can do an easy lookup of the integer id based on the string returned.

```
int id = spinnerMap.get(spinner.getSelectedItem());
```